# cassandra nodetool refresh from host

Tags: shell, cassandra

I want to execute the Cassandra "nodetool refresh" command outside the container.

Do we have a command to execute via shell script?
my shell script nodetool_refresh.sh is in host.

I want to mention that I don't want docker exec command .

Comment: docker exec <container> <path to script>

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to run docker exec thats the plan.

Comment: Than you could install nodetool on your machine and run nodetool refresh from there.

Comment: Running the nodetool refresh outside of container will require that you expose JMX outside of container that will increase a security attack surface